# What to do if no one answers a Question?

Tags: discussion

What should be done if a question goes unanswered for a long time? (as an example, one of my questions about MouseHover is still unanswered.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is taken from meta.stackexchange.com

[**How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-my-old-unanswered-questions)

> 1. You can "bump" your thread by editing the question to **provide status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the question yourself**. I usually do that unless I really hit a dead end with no further clues to follow. Some times I eventually bring about enough understanding to realise the answer, and thus post a resolution to my own problem.
> 2. If you have [at least **75** rep points](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), you can offer a **bounty**, promising to give some of your points to the person who correctly answers your question.

Answer (score 7):

There are at least two options:

- edit the question to add more detail or any updated detail - this will bump the question to the top of the list
- create a bounty by giving up some rep - this attracts more attention